# VScodeでerbファイルをコメントアウトできない

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, html, vscode, erb

VScodeを使用してerbファイルを編集中、コメントアウトのショートカットキーである
<kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>/</kbd> を押すと`//`が出てきてしまいコメントアウトできません。
これはerbファイルがhtmlファイルと同一視されているためなのでしょうか？

settings.jsonファイルは下のようになっています。

```
{
    "editor.tabSize": 2,
    "editor.renderWhitespace": true,
    "files.associations": {
        "*.erb": "erb"
    },
    "emmet.includeLanguages": {
        "erb": "html"
    },
    "workbench.iconTheme": "vscode-icons",
    "editor.formatOnPaste": true,
    "editor.formatOnSave": true,
    "editor.formatOnType": true,
    "html.format.endWithNewline": true,
    "solargraph.autoformat": true,
    "files.insertFinalNewline": true,
    "workbench.editor.closeEmptyGroups": false,
    "files.trimFinalNewlines": true,
    "workbench.editor.enablePreview": false
}
```

Comment: VS Code の右下にどの言語として開いているかの表示がでますが、.erb ファイルでは何が表示されていますか？

Answer (score 1):

拡張機能の"Ruby"（発行者名がPeng Lvとなっているもの）をインストールして有効にすると、意図する動作になるのではないでしょうか。
（"Ctrl + Shift + X"で拡張機能タブが開くので、そこでRubyと検索すれば出てきます）

上記の`settings.json`を反映させた状態でこの拡張機能を有効にすると、
html.erbファイルがerbファイルと認識されました（右下に表示される言語モードが"erb"になりました）。
その状態で"cmd + /"を行うと、下記のようにコメントアウトされました。

```
<%# text %>
```